# Alternatives to remove Unity splash screen after developing a game with the free version?

Tags: unity, licensing

I developed a simple game using the free version of Unity. I want to understand how much it would cost me to remove the Unity Splash Screen to know if it's worth it.

Right now Unity professional edition costs $75 per month, does this mean I have to pay every month while the game is on the app store or can I pay just for the month I have to release the game so I remove the Unity Splash Screen and that's all (provided I don't need to update the game later)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [Unity store page](https://store.unity3d.com/), the $75/month subscription is locked in for 12 months, so it would cost $900 for one year. (click the $75/month price link for subscription details)

If you wanted to update your game after one year, you would need another subscription after that, so maybe $1,800 all up if you plan on updating your game after a year.

Or, you could pay the full one-off $1,500 price and have Unity 5 Pro be yours forever.

---

Edit: according to the [Unity FAQ](https://unity3d.com/unity/faq):

> **Do I need iOS + Android Pro in order to build to iOS + Android devices?**
>
> Unity Personal Edition includes deployment to Android and iOS with the Personal Edition splash screen. To deploy to iOS and Android without the Personal Edition Splash Screen you must purchase Unity Professional Edition together with iOS Pro and/or Android Pro deployment add-ons.

So it sounds like you would also need another $75/month or one-off $1,500 cost for the iOS Pro Add-on on top of Unity Pro.

So all up, you'd have to either pay for subscriptions for one year for both Unity Pro and iOS Pro for a total of $1,800 (assuming you weren't ever going to update your app after one year), *or* pay $3,000 for both as a one-off.

Comment: On second thought the splash screen doesn't look so bad... Hah

Comment: Go with Unreal engine, unity have made the mistake of trashing indie developers with their bad business modal.

Answer (score -3):

On android there is a file called splash.png that you can simply replace with something else.

Comment: Your answer isn't addressing the question asked, but you can try to expand it to help the asker. Otherwise, if you just wanted to comment the question, you shouldn't circumvent the reputation points limitation, just keep participating in the community to gain enough reputation and comment; if you use answers as comments, other users may downvote you and this leads to unwanted rep points loss.